# xamarin ios: how to call NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler method?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I would like to log any exception occurring when the app is crashed. In ios, it has a method called NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler, how can I call this method in Xamarin?

Answer (score 2):

According to the answer provided here: [MonoTouch: uncaughtExceptionHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491813/monotouch-uncaughtexceptionhandler) MonoTouch generates its own uncaught exception handler.

To catch and log any uncaught exception, wrap UIApplication.Main() in a try catch block.

Comment: This also will NOT catch exceptions on other threads. E.g. if you call ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem.  Be sure to use try/catch inside those. Ex: `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( delegate { try { ...your code... } catch {...} } );`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler by using P/Invoke: [see my answer](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8030/nssetuncaughtexceptionhandler)

Comment: Your answer is not complete. What is the type definition for NSUncaughtExceptionHandler you mention?