# Create NSException from IntPtr

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, nsexception

I referring to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30869557/426227):

```
private static void MyUncaughtExceptionHandler(IntPtr exception)
{
    // this is not working because NSException(IntPtr) is a protected constructor
    var e = new NSException(exception);
    // ...
}
```

How can I create an exception here?

Should I do somehting like this?

```
NSException exception = (NSException)ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject(handle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the correct answer yourself:

```
NSException exception = (NSException) ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject (handle);
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a custom subclass of `NSException` and expose the protected constructor. Your `ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject` should also work (I think - not 100% sure).

You can create a really simple subclass like this:

```
public MyNSException : NSException {
    public MyNSException(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { }
}
```

And then you should be able to create your `NSException` like so:

```
var exception = new MyNSException(exception);
```

I haven't tried using any of this code, but this should get you compiling.